# Highlight specific dates on boostrap embedded/inline datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker

How can I highlight specific dates on boostrap embedded/inline datepicker?

I tried this:

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
    $('#datepicker').datepicker({
        format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
        minDate:new Date(),
        startDate: "now"
    });
});
```

Html:

```
<div id="datepicker"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `beforeShowDay` to highlight specific date like below.

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LcqM7/1034/)

```
var active_dates = ["16/6/2017"]; // Highlite date
$('#datepicker').datepicker({

  beforeShowDay: function(date) {
    var d = date;
    var curr_date = d.getDate();
    var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
    var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
    var formattedDate = curr_date + "/" + curr_month + "/" + curr_year;
    if ($.inArray(formattedDate, active_dates) != -1) {
      return {
        classes: 'highlight'
      };
    }
    return;
  }
});
```